# Get duration of a Twilio Conference

Tags: twilio

I see that `DialCallDuration` works for regular calls but it specifically says that it does not get returned for the `<call>` verb for conference calls. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the duration for conference calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one answer that's a bit of a workaround: you can grab the duration of the recording of the conference. It may not be perfect but that gets me pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

First need to set `statusCallback` for conference for `leave`. So when any leg finish, it will come with leg `CallSid`.

Now you need to fetch the call detail with the 'CallSid' for desired leg duration.

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{Sid}.json
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, having worked on this problem as well, I think your best bet here is going to be to use `statusCallback` event and capture the information about the conference. You can change the `statusCallbackEvent` parameters so that you only capture the `start` and `end` events, which signify the start and end of the conference. You'll have to persist this information somewhere, but it should allow you to capture the duration of the conference.

An alternative, but similar approach, would be to only capture the `end` status callback event and use the `ConferenceSid` parameter that Twilio provides in the callback to find the conference (via the REST API) and calculated the difference between the `conference.date_created` and current time.